# Can someone clarify the recursive step in this function that finds all possible permutations for a string?

Tags: recursion, permutation

This isn't my code, but was taken from elsewhere:

```
var permutations = [];
function doPerm(str, arr) {
if (typeof (str) == 'string') str = str.split('');
if (str.length == 0) permutations.push(arr.join(''));
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var x = str.splice(i, 1); 
    arr.push(x); 
    doPerm(str, arr);
    arr.pop(); 
    str.splice(i, 0, x); 
}
```

I understand the algorithm behind the code, but I can't seem to track what's happening behind the recursion. It would help a lot if someone drew a tree with a simple example where: str = 'abc'

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is just using an algorithm over and over again to achieve a desired result. In this case you're calling `doPerm` which modifies `str`, places it in `arr`, and then the function calls itself to work out the next permutation.

There's a really good article explaining recursion [here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Practices/Solving-Problems-with-Recursion/).